# Method somehow returning error-prone Array

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using `phantomJS` combined with `fs` to find and render HTML files. To start. I use `fs.list` which is supposed to return an Array. Whenever I try to mutate that array, either with lodash or by calling the array's `splice` method, I get a RangeError. Why would I get a RangeError just by calling `splice`? Here is the code:

```
var _ = require('lodash'), fs = require('fs'), webpage = require('webpage');
var path = '/home/tahsis/projects/tiForms/testing/input', files = fs.list(path), page = webpage.create();
console.log(files.length);
files.splice(0, 2);
console.log(files.length);
```

`length` is properly logged as 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `fs.list()` seems to be an immutable array in PhantomJS < v2.0.0 (I've tried it with v1.9.7 and v2.0.0). You can't manipulate it for example by splicing it.

You can however, convert it into a mutable array. There are many ways to do it. [James M Greene suggests](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11061#issuecomment-15702000):

```
files = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(files));
```

Comment: Missed that while the documentation has switched over 2.0, npm still installs 1.9 by default because 2.0 is unstable.

Comment: There is an npm package which is called "phantomjs2" if you want to install a newer PhantomJS.